# Why would jmap -permstat report more than MaxPermSize bytes used?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, permgen

I've taken a the `jmap -permstat` output of a JVM (reported as version 24.76-b04), it reports the following totals:

> total = 5190  76930   1031431696      N/A     alive=1, dead=5189      N/A

Which should be the number of entries, classes using this information, bytes used for metadata and liveness information.

Now, I wonder why it would report `1031431696 bytes`, just shy of a Gigabyte when I startup my VM with `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. Can someone shed light on how the number is calculated?

Don't know if it's relevant but this is using Rhino with ~3k entries being `DefiningClassLoader`s.

Comment: Check this tool: {JDK_PATH}\bin\jvisualvm.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked a bit at the code for the `jmap -permstat` implementation. The bytes used value is an estimation based on sizes for the different types of data a classloader loads (methods, fields, interfaces etc).

The top level method that does the size calculation for a loaded class is `sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PermStat.computeSize`:

```
private long computeSize(InstanceKlass k) {
  long size = 0L;

  // the InstanceKlass object itself
  size += k.getObjectSize();

  // Constant pool
  ConstantPool cp = k.getConstants();
  size += cp.getObjectSize();
  size += objectSize(cp.getCache());
  size += objectSize(cp.getTags());

  // Interfaces
  size += arraySize(k.getLocalInterfaces());
  size += arraySize(k.getTransitiveInterfaces());

  // Inner classes
  size += objectSize(k.getInnerClasses());

  // Fields
  size += objectSize(k.getFields());

  // Methods
  ObjArray methods = k.getMethods();
  int nmethods = (int) methods.getLength();
  if (nmethods != 0L) {
     size += methods.getObjectSize();
     for (int i = 0; i < nmethods; ++i) {
        Method m = (Method) methods.getObjAt(i);
        size += m.getObjectSize();
        size += objectSize(m.getConstMethod());
     }
  }

  // MethodOrdering - an int array that records the original
  // ordering of methods in the class file
  size += arraySize(k.getMethodOrdering());

  return size;
}
```

My guess is that this estimation fails horribly in your case. The reason it fails is hard to say without checking the object size calculations in detail for your JVM version in combination with the characteristics of the loaded classes in your application.

Also, the [Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE 6 with HotSpot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html) mentions that the value is an approximation.

Bottom line, take the bytes used value with a grain of salt.

Comment: Good enough for me. Since the Rhino classloaders only hold a handful of classes (often times, a single class), I can probably run those numbers synthetically and find out where it goes amiss. Thanks for finding the right spot in the code! I'll follow up with a more detailed explanation when I had the time to get some numbers here.